# Imprimir salida de la consola en archivo txt usando Python

Tags: python

Cómo se pueden guardar la salida de un programa de python en un archivo txt?

Comment: Igual que en cualquier otro ejecutable, al lanzarlo desde una terminal añade al comando `> fichero.txt`, por ejemplo: `python programa.py > fichero.txt`

Comment: Supongo que el problema es que luego ya no ves nada porque todo está siendo volcado al archivo de texto. De todas maneras se puede usando `python script.py > out.log | tail -f out.log`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suponiendo que lo estás ejecutando sobre cualquier sistema Unix, tienes diversas formas de forzar la salida en un fichero.

Por una parte, si quieres que **toda la salida sea redirigida al fichero**, deberías de utilizar:

```
python code.py &> file.txt
```

En el caso de querer **limitar solo a la salida estándar** a tal fichero deberías redirigir sólo *STDOUT*:

```
python code.py > file.txt
```

o, **para error**, *STDERR*:

```
python code.py 2> file.txt
```

Como casos específicos, si quieres que se guarde **sólo la salida estándar**, pero no la salida de error, el código a utilizar sería:

```
python code.py > file.txt 2> /dev/null
```

Y, finalmente, si quieres que se guarde **en un fichero además de ver, en pantalla**, tal resultado, puedes utilzar *tee*:

```
python code.py | tee file.txt
```